# Sample very top left pixel colour

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I have an gradient that I'm forceably putting on an image , Example:

[image]

I need to sample the top left pixel of the image so that I can make the background colour of the header the same as the image.

Here's what I've tried, it seems to be close, but it's not completely accurate...

```
elem = document.createElement('canvas'); 
isCanvasSupported = !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext('2d')); 


analyseAndDraw($('img#load').get(0));    


function analyseAndDraw(image) { 
  if (isCanvasSupported) {
      // Create the canvas and context
      var can = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

      // Set the canvas dimensions
      $(can).attr('width', image.width);
      $(can).attr('height', image.height);

      // Draw the image to the canvas
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);



      var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;    

      var newColour = 'rgb(' + [data[0], data[1], data[2]] + ')';


      //Set the header background to the average RGB value
      $('body').css('background', newColour);    

  } else {
      $('body').css('background', 'transparent');
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color construction is not right. It should be

```
var newColour = 'rgb(' + [data[0]+ ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2]] + ')';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set rgb separate by commas like this

```
rgb('RED COLOR VALUE' , 'GREEN COLOR VALUE' , 'BLUE COLOR VALUE');
```

OLD :

```
var newColour = 'rgb(' + [data[0], data[1], data[2]] + ')';
```

NEW :

```
var newColour = 'rgb(' + [data[0]+ ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2]] + ')';
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, so stupid of me... Mohkhan was first though so I marked him as the correct answer but thankyou!